# Ubuntu on VMware/Virtual Box will not launch

Tags: boot, virtualbox, vmware

I recently built a new computer, X570 MSI Carbon Gaming, Ryzen 7 3800x, 64 GB RAM, Nvidia 2080 ti card with Windows 10 as the core OS. I built this for a few reasons but labs are a big reason. I am trying to install Linux, Debian versions, Kali and Ubuntu in VMware pro and then VirtualBox.

I can install the images on the PC but after that and the Linux OS goes to boot the OS will not load and I am getting the following errors with a <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>t</kbd>. The same errors are showing up in both VMWare and VirtualBox.

I have been searching online for a while and have had no luck getting anything useful here.
I have called MSI and they just said I needed to have the VM enabled check on the options in the UEFI. I was hoping someone here could help me figure out what is going on here.

Here is a screen capture of the FAILED errors:

[image: Screen capture of the FAILED errors]

Answer (score 0):

Reinstalled OS, some reason it works now.